# javascript OOP:reach the method inside object

Tags: javascript, object-literal

Here is the my question

```
var panel = {
    _pnlHeaderContainer: $('.panelHeader'),
    _pnlHeaderString:"",
    //private method
    _Write: function (pnlHeaderString) { return this._pnlHeaderContainer.html(pnlHeaderString); },
    Clear: function () { return this._pnlBaslikContainer.html(""); },
   // _fake:this,
    Header: {
        AddEvent:"Add Event",
        Calendar: "Calendar",
    }

};
```

what I wanna achieve is using the _Write method in Header object
something like this

```
Header: {
        AddEvent:this._Write("Add Event"),
        Calendar: "Calendar",
        }
```

trying to run this code like this    panel.Header.AddEvent; but it says me Write is not a function

Comment: You haven't asked a question. What's wrong with that code?

Comment: I feel that perhaps [this is what you're asking](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616202/self-references-in-object-literal-declarations)?

Comment: :this._Write("Add Event"), cant reach here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to provide a `context` when creating a class

```
function Panel(){
    var context = this;

    this._pnlHeaderContainer = $('.panelHeader');
    this._pnlHeaderString = "";

    this._Write = function(pnlHeaderString){ 
        return context._pnlHeaderContainer.html(pnlHeaderString); 
    };
    this.Clear = function(){ 
        return context._pnlBaslikContainer.html(""); 
    };
    this.Header = {
        AddEvent: function(){ return context._Write("Add Event"); },
        Calendar: "Calendar",
    };
}
var panelObject = new Panel();

// Do whatever you want...
panelObject.Header.AddEvent();
```